# small card game with Python and Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on a program with Python and Kivy. I would like to program a game, whereby the program issues a random card from a skat deck (that already works fine!). Then a task should appear after each card. The task always depends on the number or the picture: For example, after every 7 the task "Everyone should drink 3 sips!" come.

Can someone help me with this? Unfortunately, I can't get any further.

Thank you and best regards

One of the Codes (Output of the program in German):

```
from random import randint

# Global variables
cardSuits = ['PIK', 'HERZ', 'KARO', 'KREUZ']
courtCards = ['BUBE', 'DAME', 'KÖNIG']
cardRanks = ['ASS'] + ['{}'.format(x) for x in range(7, 11)] + courtCards
cardsDrawn = []

# Functions
def draw_a_card(self, *args):

    # a deck of card has 32 playing cards
    if len(cardsDrawn) >= 32:
        print("\tcards_drawn=", sorted(cardsDrawn))
        return 'Alle Karten wurden ausgeteilt!'
    
    # Example set of 32 playing cards; 8 of each suit clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades
    suit = randint(1, 4)
    rank = randint(1, 8)
    card = '{0}-{1:02d}'.format(suit, rank)

    if card not in cardsDrawn:
        cardsDrawn.append(card)
        return '{1} {0}'.format(cardRanks[rank-1], cardSuits[suit-1])
        
    else:
        return draw_a_card(self, args)
```

Comment: Can you just use the card rank as an index into a list of tasks?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I've tried this before, but couldn't get it right. Can you maybe tell me how? Then I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a list of tasks and using the card rank as an index into the list. Something like:

```
from random import randint

# Global variables
cardSuits = ['PIK', 'HERZ', 'KARO', 'KREUZ']
courtCards = ['BUBE', 'DAME', 'KÖNIG']
cardRanks = ['ASS'] + ['{}'.format(x) for x in range(7, 11)] + courtCards
cardsDrawn = []
tasks = ["unused", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task4", "task5", "task6",  "Everyone should drink 3 sips!", "task8"]

# Functions
def draw_a_card(self, *args):

    # a deck of card has 32 playing cards
    if len(cardsDrawn) >= 32:
        print("\tcards_drawn=", sorted(cardsDrawn))
        return 'Alle Karten wurden ausgeteilt!'
    
    # Example set of 32 playing cards; 8 of each suit clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades
    suit = randint(1, 4)
    rank = randint(1, 8)
    card = '{0}-{1:02d}'.format(suit, rank)
    the_task = tasks[rank]

    if card not in cardsDrawn:
        cardsDrawn.append(card)
        return '{1} {0}'.format(cardRanks[rank-1], cardSuits[suit-1])
        
    else:
        return draw_a_card(self, args)
```

Perhaps add the task to the return string.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot! However, the tasks are not yet displayed in the output. Has that to do with Kivy? Or is that still due to the Python code?

Comment: You can add a line: `print(the_task)`.